# SQL Server and Entity Framework : transaction is failing in one use case

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am using C#, SQL Server, Entity Framework 6 in my code. While inserting a record in table I get an exception, but record is inserted into the table.

While doing operation1 I got below error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

This issue occur very rarely.

My code is look like this:

```
Public Void UploadData(Request request)
{
    // Creating db context.
    // Creating TransactionScope object.
    TransactionOptions _oTransactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();
    oTransactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    oTransactionOptions.Timeout = new TimeSpan(hour, min, sec);

    TransactionScope  TransactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, oTransactionOptions);

    try
    {
        // Doing operation1
        // Doing operation2
        // Doing operation3
        // Doing operation4

        TransactionScope.Complete();
        TransactionScope.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         TransactionScope.Dispose();
          // logging error.
    }
    finally
    {
         // Disposing context.
    }
}
```

Comment: It's those `doing operation1` lines that cause blocking, not TransactionScope itself. It's impossible to help because you don't post the relevant information. Besides, DbContext.SaveChanges uses transactions already. Why did you use an explicit transaction? And why `try/finally` instead of `using`? These are *not* identical. `using` will call `Dispose()` even in cases where `finally` isn't called

Comment: If your operations time out, you should investigate why, not try to cover it up. What does SSMS Activity Monitor show when blocking occurs? Is there a blocked query? Who's blocking?